# Spring Data Mongo - Inheritance and Embeddable

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have a `Customer` entity with a list of `Vehicles`:

```
@Document
public class Customer {
  private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

  //... getters, setters
}
```

`Vehicle` is an abstract class with a few subtypes:

```java
public abstract class Vehicle {
}

@TypeAlias("CAR")
public class Car {
}

@TypeAlias("BOAT")
public class Boat {
}

@TypeAlias("MOTORBIKE")
public class Motorbike {
}
```

Is there any way to have Spring handle this use case? i.e. if I save a `Car` and a `Boat` against a customer, have them correctly hydrate when querying the `Customer`? At the moment, I'm getting a `java.lang.InstantiationError` as Spring Data seems to be trying to create an instance of the `Vehicle` abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue.

Basically, I needed to add the package containing the `Vehicle` classes to get scanned to my Mongo Configuration class as follows:

```java
public class CustomerDbConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  ... 

  @Override
  protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
    Collection<String> mappingBasePackages = new ArrayList<>();
    mappingBasePackages.add(Vehicle.class.getPackageName());

    return mappingBasePackages;
  }

}
```

I think the above should work in most cases. My understanding is the above might not be necessary if Configuration class is within the same package as the `Vehicle` classes however, in my case, they're in two different packages.

Additionally, it was a bit more complicated on my side since I have multiple Mongo databases with different configurations and different `MongoTemplate` beans.

Initially, I was creating the `MongoTemplate` as follows:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "customerMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate customerMongoTemplate() {
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  MappingMongoConverter converter = (MappingMongoConverter) mongoTemplate.getConverter();
  converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
  converter.afterPropertiesSet();
  return mongoTemplate;
}
```

However, getting the `MappingMongoConverter` this way, via the `MongoTemplate` means that `getMappingBasePackages` was never being called. I tried to get converter instead by doing the following:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "customerMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate customerMongoTemplate() {
  return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
}
```

however it didn't work, as the `mongoDbFactory()` and `mappingMongoConverter()` were returning beans for a different MongoDB configuration... This would be the ideal solution for me, but not sure how to get it working reliably with multiple configuration classes.

In the end, I managed to get working reliably as follows:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "customerMongoTemplate")
public MongoTemplate customerMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
  SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());

  MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext = mongoMappingContext();
  mongoMappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
  mongoMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet();

  MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), mongoMappingContext);
  converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
  converter.afterPropertiesSet();

  return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
}
```

I'm not entirely comfortable with the above approach, it's somewhat finicky and could potentially cause issues with new versions of Spring, however, it does work.

Comment: Bunch of stuff doesn't work if springs does not manage the classes. This tutorial shows a seemingly clean way of using multiple instances of Mongo DB - separating entities at the package level. Seems more like the spring way - https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot/

Comment: I am doing something similar to that tutorial in my codebase although my use case is a little more complicated since I need custom converters and package scanning for type aliases. However, in my case, the MongoTemplate is being managed my Spring? Which part will break down, do you think? Would it be solved by creating the `MongoDbFactory` and `MappingMongoConverter` as separate beans rather than creating them within the method creating the `MongoTemplate` bean?